# Procedure in Taylor series - Understanding derivation

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

this is my first time posting so hopefully I'm not messing things up.

I understand the general idea behind Taylor series, but the I don't understand what's meant by *"We may repeat this procedure"* in this [book (Riley's Mathematical methods)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uHtI.jpg). I've written in green what I think I understand, and the part in red is the source of my problem.

It looks to me that the *procedure* is substituting derivatives of $f(x)$ into $f(a+h)$, but $f(a+h)$ only contains $f'(x)$, and no higher order derivatives? So how am I supposed to "repeat the procedure"?

I know there are other ways of achieving the end result, but I it is this particular method I'm interested in learning.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above line of your book perhaps means we'd keep doing integration by parts again and again and will obtain a series which is **Taylor Series** .

Integration by Parts:

$$ \int u(x)v'(x) \, dx = u(x)v(x) - \int v(x) u'(x) \, dx  $$

Do, that to the equation which is just before *(algebra)* denoted in green, you'll get Taylor Series.

Comment: Knowing that the procedure is using integration by parts, I would argue this question " https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745244/taylor-expansion-integration-by-parts-and-the-integration-of-dt " is an answer to my above problem.

Note This was written as an answer before, but as per request by user Yves Daoust, I made it into a comment